# How to select an item that does not contain a class/id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the selector that matches the following:

[Title](http://mysite.com/6-title) > Prints > Ginger

How do i select "Ginger" via jquery

code for the above are:

```
             <span class="selectednav">
                    <a href="http://mysite.com/">Title</a>
                    <span class="navigation-pipe"> > </span>
                    <a href="http://mysite.com/20-prints">Prints</a>
                    <span class="navigation-pipe"> > </span>
                Ginger
             </span>
```

Any help would much be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Could you tidy up the HTML? The indentation and parent/child elements need to be clearer.

Comment: what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: i am using this to have the link in the sidebar navigation 'selected' - by matching it with the last breadcrumb item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full edit sorry first answer not adapted // although not sure this works to be honest

```
$('.selectednav').contents().filter(
                 function() { if (this.nodeType == 3) $(this).wrap("<span class='orphan'></span>"); });

$orphan = $('.selectednav').find(".orphan");
```

edit in one line for perf sake :

```
 $orphan = $('.selectednav').contents().filter(
                 function() { if (this.nodeType == 3) $(this).wrap("<span class='orphan'></span>"); }).end().find(".orphan");
```

also each would work instead of filter

then if only to get the text this should do

```
 orphantext= $('.selectednav').contents().filter(
                 function() { return this.nodeType == 3; })
               .text();
```

Comment: seems to be workable.. this would wrap ginger in the span 'orphan'

Comment: yes it should but you just want the text it seems so you might not need to wrap nothing and  `filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}) .text()`  might work as well

Answer (score 0):

Something like $(".selectednav").find(".navigation-pipe").last() should work.

Answer (score 0):

This Link might be what your looking for

[Transversing](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_filtering.asp)

I think the code may look like this if you have a div around the code you have presented

```
$("div span").last()
```

Comment: What if you use the .Html() method and replace the entire code with what you want?